# Center Google Map based on markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, centering

I want to center Google Map based on dynamically loaded markers. Right now I am displaying two markers on the map (see script.js file):

```
$mapster.mapster('addMarker', {
  location: 'Golden Gate Bridge, San Francisco, CA',
  content: 'Example text 2'
});

$mapster.mapster('addMarker', {
  lat: 37.751350,
  lng: -122.485833,
  content: '<div style="color: #f00;">Example text 1</div>'
});
```

Everything works fine, because I defined the coordinates for centering the map (see map-options.js file):

```
mapster.MAP_OPTIONS = {
  center: {
    lat: 37.791350,
    lng: -122.435883
  },
  zoom: 10,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  scrollwheel: true,
  draggable: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
  },
  panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  },
  cluster: {
    options: {
      styles: [{
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclusterer/images/m2.png',
        height: 56,
        width: 55
        //textColor: '#000'
        //textSize: 12
      }, {
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
        height: 56,
        width: 55
        //textColor: '#000'
        //textSize: 12
      }]
    }
  },
  geocoder: true
};
```

How could I center my Google Map based on any loaded markers? I basically want to achieve something like this:
[Center a Google Map based on Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481091/center-a-google-map-based-on-markers)

Here is my code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/sduZKBXIIijhnkCIpSoR?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481091/center-a-google-map-based-on-markers) you linked, you'll want to add the coordinates to the `bounds` object as you add them, and then call `fitBounds(bounds)` on that. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

Try following this control flow:

```
let location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
let location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
let location3 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location1,
    map: map
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location2,
    map: map
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location3,
  map: map
});

let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(location1);
bounds.extend(location2);
bounds.extend(location3);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

*If you have a long listing you'll likely want to do some iterating over an array or something instead.*